# Compiling stored procedures programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, executenonquery

I have 500 stored procedures and want to compile all and if error comes it should write in file using c#. if anybody  has similar example code help

Comment: You can call SP from code C#, cant compile, only you need to compile and test in sql server itself i think.

Comment: Why not use SSDT? That way you get a lot of design-time validation that you can't get otherwise.

Comment: I agree. I think the accepted way to do this is to import your database into a database proejct and compile the project, just like you would a C# project. stored procedures have dependencies. You can't say a stored procedure compiles until it actually has all dependent views, tables etc.

Comment: Compile stored procedures? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What sort of errors are you talking about? Binding errors (missing tables or views), or do you mean syntax errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the command to alter a store procedure once, if the execution of the command encounters an error, it means that your store procedure has a problem.
You can get the store procedures script through the following script
Of course, this script gives the Create and you have to change it to Alter

```sql
select name, object_definition(object_id) 
from sys.procedures
```